# Event pattern for AWS Secrets Manager with filter pattern

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-secrets-manager, aws-event-bridge

I want to run a Lambda when a specific secret is modified/created/removed from Secrets Manager.

I have deployed a cloudwatch event rule with the below event pattern with a target lambda.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.secretsmanager"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateSecret",
      "UpdateSecret",
      "DeleteSecret",
      "PutSecretValue"
    ]
  }
}
```

The rule gets triggered for **any** API request hitting secretsmanager.amazonaws.com. Is there a way to filter on specific secrets that interest me?

Comment: The lambda can do that, right?

Comment: if I handle that within the lambda, it means the lambda get invoked unnecessarily for events not pertinent to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateSecret", "UpdateSecret", "DeleteSecret", "PutSecretValue"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "secretId": [{
        "prefix": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:**AWS-REGION**:**AWS-ACCNT-ID**:secret:**PREFIX_SECRET_NAME**"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For event filters we have to use the supported methods to perform filter operations as it won't support wildcard to capture the matching events.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

requestParameters and secretId:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateSecret",
      "UpdateSecret",
      "DeleteSecret",
      "PutSecretValue"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "secretId": [
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:secret:secret_name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the previous answers and found not working, following I have created and it's working.

```
        {
          "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
          "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
          "detail": {
            "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
            "eventName": ["PutSecretValue", "UpdateSecret", "RotationSucceeded"],
            "responseElements": {
              "$or": [{
                "arn": ["arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:secret:your-secret-name"]
              }, {
                "arn": ["arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:secret:your-secret-name1"]
              }]
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, It triggers an AWS Lambda function whenever there are changes in the two mentioned AWS Secrets Managers. Here's the example for yaml syntax :

```
SecretsManagerEventRule:
  Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
  DependsOn:
    - LambdaFunctionfunction
  Properties:
    Description: Trigger for Secrets manager changes
    Name: Project1secretManagerChanges
    EventPattern:
      source:
        - aws.secretsmanager
      detail-type:
        - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
      detail:
        eventSource:
          - secretsmanager.amazonaws.com
        eventName:
          - CreateSecret
          - UpdateSecret
          - DeleteSecret
          - PutSecretValue
        responseElements:
          arn:
            - arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account-id>:secret:<secret-name>
            - arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account-id>:secret:<secret-name>
    State: 'ENABLED'
    Targets:
      - Arn: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionfunction.Arn
        Id: 'LambdaFunctionTarget'
```